# Is there a software methodology newer than Agile?

Tags: project-management, agile, development-process

Is there a software development process out there newer than agile?

I mean, waterfall, then agile, then what?

Comment: The next step is FrAgile Development ;-).

Comment: FrAgile has already caught on.

Comment: What about "WAGILEFALL"?

Comment: voted to close because (1) the question indicates that you have done zero research, (2) your update is complaining about the way the site is designed to work to eliminate poor questions, and (3) "behave bad developers" is insulting, arrogant, rude, and childish. Is that the kind of comment you were looking for?

Answer (score 11):

It helps if we stop thinking of Scrum being equal to Agile.

Agile is a set of principles, mostly aimed at reducing waste. Scrum is a process which reduces waste and thus is considered Agile. XP is another set of processes which reduce waste and thus are considered Agile.

Lean is the next step, but it is not contradictory to Agility, it is another principle aimed at reducing work in progress. Scrum isn't really Lean, but if you take a few hints from Kanban, you can make Scrum much Leaner very easily. (google "Scrumban")

Answer (score 8):

There's probably too much of looking for the next "silver bullet" in this business. Most of what is done lately is improving specific practices of the software development (TDD, BDD, etc) and project management (Kanban) crafts.  The main principles of agile are fundamental and there is no compelling rush to change to the "next" thing, but rather to get more to actually use them.

Comment: AMEN!!!  The problems with software development aren't because Agile is failing us it is because so few companies are willing (or able) to take that leap of faith and loosen the reigns to allow Agile development practices to benefit their bottom line.

Answer (score 1):

I think agile is the latest and greatest in these. I think agile is wide open enough that it shouldn't change a lot, especially in it's name, but evolve and encompass new techniques. But at the moment as far as I can tell, agile is probably will be the last thing till new terminology comes up (not so much ideas). To me agile is simple common sense, or things I was taught years ago to be productive and produce a strong product (regardless of what it is, programming, sport teams, construction, etc..) wrapped up in terminology for today's youths. In short agile is just time proven techniques that are known to work.

Answer (score 0):

it's a nice question. A lot of Scrum adepts see Scrum as the silver bullet and 'one size fits all'.
I think when a lot of people start using scrum, we finally have the enjoyment of people actually following some kind of method, and by using Scrum, finally learning about how much they can build.

And for my favorite one: Scrum sais you have to look back on your process, something that nowadays is seldom done.
I think when all project teams around the world start looking back at their (Scrum) process, we will have a very much improved (Scrum) process which will probably be named otherwise to differ between the Scrum as we now know it and the newer version.